# how can I change the language of bootbox.dialog which is used in javascript?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, locale, bootbox

I am doing this with the use of locale but it didn't work for me And While searching I got something from http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html but didn't find helpful.
Please suggest me what can I do for this?

Comment: did you follow the docs? http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-locales read "please note" at the bottom of the locales list

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to use a locale other than `en`, you need to do one of these:

- Use `bootbox.all.js` (or the min version)
- Add a reference to `bootbox.locales.js` (or the min version) AFTER `bootbox.js`
- Add a reference to the locale file(s) matching the locales you want to use, found in the locales directory in the project source, (again) AFTER `bootbox.js`.

This only applies to the v5.x version - if you don't need Bootstrap 4 support, the v4.x branch of Bootbox includes all of the locales in `bootbox.js`.